# Magento 2.4.3-p1 upgrade - Setup:upgrade stuck at Magento_Customer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.4.3 to Magento 2.4.3-p1 using composer and successfully new version upgrade but when run upgrade command but process stuck not progress process of from Data install/update Magento_Customer.

Also, not showing any error in the error log and apache2 error log, I have tried all possibilities but it's last stuck in Magento_Customer

Comment: Check PHP variable like memory limit and max_execution_time 18000, max_input_time 18000, max_input_vars 50000, memory_limit 4096M

Also you can check var/log/ for error like below
 
Error filtering template: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Comment: It's fetching error me but I have set all variable and again run all command then it's successfully done

Comment: Have you found solution, I got same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> You can check by run below command:

```
strace -s 99 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

More about [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace#:%7E:text=strace%20is%20a%20diagnostic%2C%20debugging,and%20changes%20of%20process%20state.)

> **Also, check your MySQL has not run any related process, you found then kill it. (Not KILL ALL, only related Processes need to kill)**

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST

kill ProcessID
```

> **In My case customer_visitor table cause an error and stops the command. After debugging more in DB, there are many entries, so he takes more time to run and stop the upgrade command execution.**

> **I remove all entries from **customer_visitor** table and then It's working.**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE customer_visitor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the var/vendor folder existing or not ?

If not then download Magento 2.4.3.p1 and upload vendor folder in var/ directory.

then run again setup:upgrade command it's working.